# How to use EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition for entity reference field?

Tags: 7, entities

Suppose, we have an entity "*song*", that has an entity reference field, called "*authors*":

[image]

I added a filter for this field as a group of checkboxes:

[image]

After the user submits the form with checkboxes group, it must be used inside `WHERE` condition for the list of songs. So, I added the following code:

```
//query to get the list of entities
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'song');

if(!is_null($form_state['input']['field_authors'][LANGUAGE_NONE]))
{
    $query->fieldCondition('field_authors', /* what to put here? */, 
            $form_state['input']['field_authors'][LANGUAGE_NONE], 'in');
}
```

I don't understand, what value to put into column parameter. I tried `target_id`, but it doesn't work. Here is the description of `field_data_field_authors` table:

```
DESCRIBE field_data_field_authors;
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type             | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                  | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                 | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id             | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language                | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_authors_target_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Take the database column name for the value (field_authors_target_id), remove the name of the field (field_authors), and you're left with the column name (target_id). That recipe will work for any type of field. If it's not working, your problem is somewhere else (e.g. `$form_state['input']['field_authors'][LANGUAGE_NONE]` doesn't contain what you're expecting)

Comment: It takes the field name of the table that we need to compare.
So you can use 'field_authors_target_id'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `'target_id'`

Your code should by this:

```
//query to get the list of entities
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'song');

if(!is_null($form_state['input']['field_authors'][LANGUAGE_NONE]))
{
    $query->fieldCondition('field_authors', 'target_id', 
            $form_state['input']['field_authors'][LANGUAGE_NONE], 'in');
}
```

You can found a good explanation here:

[How to use EntityFieldQuery with a simple text field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/105199/28275)